# Detect Alt+LeftMouse click and send delayed double-click in Autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I would like to detect the key combination (Alt + LeftMouse click) in Autohotkey. Upon detection, Autohotkey will simulate a double-click action with a delay in between the clicks.

This is my Autohotkey code. It does not work. What is wrong with it?

```
#IfWinActive Outlook
    !LButton:: ;Alt-LeftMouseClick
    {
        SendInput {Left}
        Sleep, 200 
        SendInput {Left}
        return
    }
return
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#IfWinActive Outlook

    !LButton:: ;Alt-LeftMouseClick
        ; Click ; uncommend this line if you want to click a second time after Alt+LeftMouseClick
        Sleep, 200 
        Click
    return

#IfWinActive    ; turn off context sensitivity
```

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm